Can't connect to MySQL server (110). Ruby on Rails aws codebuild deployment. AWS RDS Instance
I am trying to push some of my code to live. I am using aws codebuild and bitbucket pipeline to deploy. When I try to push my change through, the pipeline loops for 40 mins and eventually fails once the codebuild fails. Checking the logs, this is the last thing that happens before it fails.
Step 4/5 : RUN bundle exec rake db:migrate -X -s -q
 ---> Running in c556f46950e3
WARNING: Use strings for Figaro configuration. true was converted to "true".
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server (110)

It is also giving this error afterwards.
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
W, [2024-08-06T14:11:25.992477 #6]  WARN -- : Creating scope :active. Overwriting existing method Professional.active.
I, [2024-08-06T14:13:26.227433 #6]  INFO -- [Bugsnag]: Notifying https://notify.bugsnag.com of Mysql2::Error
D, [2024-08-06T14:13:26.318774 #6] DEBUG -- [Bugsnag]: Request to https://notify.bugsnag.com completed, status: 200
D, [2024-08-06T14:13:26.325314 #6] DEBUG -- [Bugsnag]: Not notifying Mysql2::Error due to ignore being signified in internal middlewares
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle exec rake db:migrate -X -s -q' returned a non-zero code: 1

I am using ruby on rails. I am worried it might be something wrong with how I handled the database but I was hoping somebody could point me in a direction of where to check for problems.
I have tried cleaning up migrations in my ruby on rails and deploying again. (I unfortunately deleted the files manually instead of the proper way)
I tried updating my rds instances as they said they needed an update
The EC2 Security Group is assigned to my RDS correctly.
For more context, This pipeline was working just fine before I tried to push in this new code, so I am thinking it might have something to do with the code. Please let me know if there is any more context I can give
branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: create & push image
          script:
            - aws/codebuild.sh demo company-demo
      - step:
          name: deploy
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - sed -i "s/TAGTOSET/demo-$BITBUCKET_COMMIT/g" ./aws/demo/ecs/task.json
            - export TASK_VERSION=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://aws/demo/ecs/task.json | jq --raw-output '.taskDefinition.revision')
            - echo "Registered ECS Task Definition $TASK_VERSION"
            - aws ecs update-service --cluster demo --service company --task-definition demo-company:$TASK_VERSION --desired-count 1 --force-new-deployment
      - step:
          name: whenever deploy
          script:
            - sed -i "s/TAGTOSET/demo-$BITBUCKET_COMMIT/g" ./aws/demo/ecs/cron-task.json
            - export TASK_VERSION=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://aws/demo/ecs/cron-task.json | jq --raw-output '.taskDefinition.revision')
            - echo "Registered ECS Task Definition $TASK_VERSION"
            - ECS_CLUSTER=demo TASK_DEFINITION=demo-cron ECS_CONTAINER=ruby AWS_REGION=ca-central-1 elastic_whenever -i demo -f config/schedule.rb

aws/codebuild.sh
PROJECT_ENV=$1
PROJECT_NAME=$2

TAG="$PROJECT_ENV-$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"

echo "Starting build for project: $PROJECT_NAME with tag: $TAG"
BUILD_INFO=`aws codebuild start-build --project-name $PROJECT_NAME --source-version $BITBUCKET_BRANCH --environment-variables-override name=TAG,value=$TAG`
echo "Build Info: $BUILD_INFO"

BUILD_ID=`echo $BUILD_INFO | jq -r '.build.id'`

while true;
do
  BUILD_STATUS=`aws codebuild batch-get-builds --ids $BUILD_ID | jq -r '.builds[0].buildStatus'`
  echo "Current Build Status: $BUILD_STATUS"

  if [[ $BUILD_STATUS == "SUCCEEDED" ]]; then
    echo $BUILD_STATUS
    exit 0
  elif [[ $BUILD_STATUS == "IN_PROGRESS" ]]; then
    echo "Build in Progress"
    sleep 10
  else
    echo "Build Failed with status: $BUILD_STATUS"
    exit 1;
  fi
done


It's pretty clear that the code cannot connect to the database -- but that's all that can be deciphered from what you supplied. Look at what you many have changed related to the database, specifically the connection information.

Ok, thanks for the feedback. I added a bunch of migrations that I later decided to delete. The only one I kept was adding "session_id" to my appointments table. As for connection information I do not know all of the ins and outs as I inherited the codebase. I edited my original post to include my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file. Let me know if that is helpful. It is failing on step 1 "create & push image" Thank you!!!

Socket error number 110 (this is the number at the end of the error message) indicates timeout error - mysql server did nit respond in time. Could be a network or database configuration issue - impossible to tell what exactly caused it based on the info you shared so far.

Sorry, about that. What additional information could I provide that would be helpful in troubleshooting? db migrations? docker configuration? I can also provide aws logs somewhere if that could help decipher the issue

Timeout combined with can't connect means that mysql client did not receive any response from the server, so it could not perform any migrations. You need to figure out what goes wrong in networking / db configuration. I think this question is on the wrong site as it is unlikely to be a programming related error.
